# Ошибка при работе с Webpack4

Tags: webpack4

Когда запускаю скрипт:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode=development --hot"    
},
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
$ yarn dev
```

> yarn run v1.5.1
>   $ NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --mode=development --hot
>   "NODE_ENV" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
>   error An unexpected error occurred: "Command failed.

Answer (score 1):

Исполняемым является `webpack-dev-server` - он должен идти первым:

`webpack-dev-server --mode=development NODE_ENV=development --hot`